# go unit test for CSV is failing

Tags: csv, unit-testing, go

I am wanting to use the csv package for a large project and I am starting with some basic tests. I cannot figure out why this unit test is failing, when it appears that the output matches the expected output.

FILE:

```
package csv

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/csv"
)

func GenerateCSV(records [][]string) (string, error) {
    buf := bytes.Buffer{}

    w := csv.NewWriter(&buf)

    for _, record := range records {
        if err := w.Write(record); err != nil {
            // handle the err
            }
    }
        w.Flush()

        if err := w.Error(); err != nil {
            // handle the error
        }

        return buf.String(), nil
    }
```

TESTFILE:

```
package csv

import "testing"

func TestGenerateCSV(t *testing.T) {

    records := [][]string{
        {"first_name","last_name","user_name"},
    }
    type args struct {
        records [][]string
    }
    tests := []struct {
        name    string
        args    args
        want    string
        wantErr bool
    }{
        // TODO: Add test cases.
        {"T1", args{records: records,}, "first_name,last_name,user_name", false},
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            got, err := GenerateCSV(tt.args.records)
            if (err != nil) != tt.wantErr {
                t.Errorf("GenerateCSV() error = %v, wantErr %v", err, tt.wantErr)
                return
            }
            if got != tt.want {
                t.Errorf("GenerateCSV() = %v, want %v", got, tt.want)
            }
        })
    }
```

When the test runs, I get this output:

```
FAIL: TestGenerateCSV
GenerateCSV() = first_name,last_name,user_name
        , want first_name,last_name,user_name
```

It seems like the test output is exactly what I called for? Can anyone help me identify what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Print with %q and you'll see the newline which is missing from your want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To catch your error add this check in your test code.

```
    if len(got) != len(tt.want) {
            t.Errorf("GenerateCSV() string len = %v, want length %v", len(got), len(tt.want))
            return
        }
```

Reason : When you are writing your record using **w.Flush**, it adds a new line.

Comment: adding this to the "want" in test case was a simple fix: `{"T1", args{records: records}, "first_name, last_name, username\n"},false},`

Comment: w.Flush() does not add the newline; newlines will be added for every w.Write(...).  w.Flush() just flushes any data in the write buffer to underlying writer. Also, while printing the difference in length might start to help understand the problem, being able to see the string-representations that don't match is at the heart of the matter.

Answer (score 0):

The test fails because your expected string doesn't contain a newline (\n) for the single-record test case:

```golang
{"T1", args{records: records}, "first_name,last_name,user_name", false},
```

It should be:

```golang
{"T1", args{records: records}, "first_name,last_name,user_name\n", false},
```

Every encoded record will have a newline.

Changing the %v to %q in your test code print-outs will make seeing the "quoted string" differences easier:

```golang
if got != tt.want {
    t.Errorf("GenerateCSV() = %q, want %q", got, tt.want)
}
```

Also, you if you don't need to do anything special to records as you are CSV-encoding them (you just want the quickest path to a CSV string), you can cut out the loop in GenerateCSV and instead use the Writer's WriteAll() method:

```golang
// GenerateCSV returns the CSV-encoded string representation of records.
func GenerateCSV(records [][]string) (string, error) {
    buf := bytes.Buffer{}

    w := csv.NewWriter(&buf)
    if err := w.WriteAll(records); err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    w.Flush()
    if err := w.Error(); err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    return buf.String(), nil
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The expected output is `first_name,last_name,user_name` but the actual output is `first_name,last_name,user_name,` (notice the extra comma at the end). This is why the test is failing.

Comment: It looks like the issue was that the test case was missing the final newline for a CSV-encoded record.